# Event tracking using Google Analysis

Tags: google-analytics

I'm adding a code on the Complete instance of a video played using jwplayer for analysis using google analytics event tracking. There I need to overwrite the base URL that is sent in the analysis code. Could you please help me with the exact parameter that I need to send for that. Below is the code I'm using to send the request to Google Analytics:
ga('send', 'event', 'Vedio', 'play', 'vedio_name');

Answer (score 1):

Use a  configuration object to set the parameters and include the page parameter with a page path as value:

```
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign',
  page: '/my/custom/pagepath/'
});
```